# whenever I import beautifulsoup4, It shows module object not callable. I have no idea why?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, typeerror

## Code :

```
from bs4 import Beautifulsoup
import requests
source = requests.get("https://www.paypal.com/in/home")
soup = Beautifulsoup(source, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

### It Give this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last) 
<ipython-input-11-b3541c73bc7b> in <module>
 
       2 import requests
       3 source = requests.get("https://www.paypal.com/in/home")
       4 soup = Beautifulsoup(source, 'lxml')
       5 print(soup)
 
 
 TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: the correct import is `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` but in your example you have `from bs4 import Beautifulsoup` can you confirm if that's a typo or is that how it appears in your code too?

Answer (score 1):

Change "from bs4 import Beautifulsoup" to "from bs4 import BeautifulSoup"

The "S" in soup needs to be in capitals as per the documentation
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/